# Occasionally sp_session_process_events() blocked until process is terminated

Tags: libspotify

While listening to music and browsing Spotify we are occasionally running into this issue where `sp_session_process_events()` never returns. Since we are putting all libspotify calls on the same thread, our app is locked up indefinitely.

All of the Spotify callbacks return instantly and any necessary processing of the data from the callbacks is scheduled on one thread for execution. Furthermore, all calls to `sp_session_process_events()` are given higher priority execution than the thread's queue. Unfortunately I have no a-b-c steps to reproduce this, but the one repeatable circumstance is that at some point `sp_session_process_events()` will not return and our thread queue will block unless our app is re-started.

Any advice in troubleshooting this would be so appreciated, it's been haunting us for months now and we've tried everything we can think of to remedy the situation to no avail. Our app is multi-threaded, but as I said before all calls will execute one at a time on the same thread for certain.